# how do you add a cookie policy to the site so it appears when a user arrives?

Tags: cookies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [eu cookie compliance](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/32584/eu-cookie-compliance)

I think this is now a legal requirement in the uk so I want to add one but I have not been able to find a module to do it. Has anyone found one or achieved it by doing a workaround?

Comment: I searched it and nothing came up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Cookie Control](https://www.drupal.org/project/cookiecontrol) module works fine to address this question.

Here is a quote from its project page:

> On May 26th 2011 a new EU originated law came into effect that requires website owners to make significant changes to their sites and may fundamentally change the whole web browsing and shopping experience for everybody.This Cookie Law is amended privacy legislation that requires websites to obtain informed consent from visitors before they can store or retrieve any information on a computer or any other web connected device.
>
> Cookie Control does just that, presenting users with clear information on whether cookies are present, linking to your privacy policy (where you should have specific information about what cookies are in use), and advising users on how to adjust browser settings and what cookies mean for them.

Comment: @Magpie That one's ok, but [EU Cookie Compliance](http://drupal.org/project/eu-cookie-compliance) is much better for UK websites

Comment: Can they do opt-in?  (I.e. no cookies until the user clicks 'Accept'.)